# Comet (Ajax Push) in Godaddy dedicated server?

Tags: comet, ape

I want to know if it's possible and I'm looking for tutorials to set it up.

APE website says that knowledge of JavaScript programming is sufficent to follow the tutorial however I haven't been able to puzzle even the first 2 lines of the tutorial.

I'm using Ubuntu. After downloading APE I have no idea what to do. I already set up SSH to access the server.

What should be my following steps or where can I find an easier to tutorial to use comet be it through APE or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your GoDaddy server is running some flavor of Linux, I don't see any reason it would not be possible. I was just looking over the documentation and I am not clear on what part you are having trouble with.  What Linux distribution are you using?  Do you have SSH access?

If you have ssh access and a root account you should be able to just follow the instructions to get APE running on the default port.

If you are running a Debian dist (Ubuntu and others) it looks like you should download the source from Git and compile it. There are instructions for the compilation there. You can learn about what you need to do wth Git by search for "clone git".

If you can be more specific about what you are having trouble with, we can probably be more helpful. But ultimately you should be able to install this on any dedicated server without issue.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. I download the .deb file. Run it through terminal or clicking. After that I don't know what to do. Honestly I have no idea why I must run it in my pc. And according to the tutorial it's already installed afterwards. Obviously I'm not saying the tutorial is wrong, I know it's my own ignorance but whatever the reason I don't know how to get it to my server.

Comment: I just enabled SSH for my server.

Comment: I think what you are misunderstanding is the part where you said "Honestly I have no idea why I must run it in my PC".  The instructions are intended to be run on the server, not on your PC. Now that you have SSH access you can SSH in, download the package (though as the instructions say the package is outdated so you might want to download the source and compile it, which you could do on your PC and then put that new package on your server) then run the package on your server to get it installed. The command line instructions are also in the tutorial. I hope that helps